# List Item Permission

Tags: permissions

If user created a new item in list then same user should not be able to modify that created item but they can add new item.

Modify option should be enabled for site owners. How to do that?

Answer (score 2):

There is no setting that allows you to do this, but what you could do is create a new permission level based on the Read Permission.  Simply add the permission to create new items.  To do this:

1. Access the site settings of the site you want to have this option
2. Click on Site Permissions
3. Click on Permission Levels
4. Enter a name for the new permission level and a description
5. Select the following options: Add Items, Open Items, View Versions, Create Alerts, View Application Pages, View Pages, Use Client Integration Features, Open

Once added, break the inheritance on the list and customize the security as needed for the list.  Use this permission level you just created to implement the requirements.

Comment: Down voted. This is essentially the same answer I provided an hour ago.

Comment: That's not fair really.  If you look at my time, I was only 5 min behind you and that's because I was still typing my answer (which is more detailed then yours) while you submitted.  I did not copy your answer it is my own

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom permission level (*Site Settings -> Site Permissions -> Permission Levels*). For example you could copy it off of Contribute and call it Restricted Contribute. Under the List Permissions just remove the Edit items and Delete items levels.

This would effectively give the user the ability to add items but unable to edit or delete them. You can continue to give your Site Owners a different permission level as you see fit.

Comment: Just an additional note that David's proposed solution requires selecting 8 options on top of following the same steps outlined in my answer. My answer simply requires unselecting 2 options from the permission levels listing and provides the same result. It is, for all intents and purposes, a cleaner answer.

Comment: Fair enough, I forgot about the copy permission level option... but there's no need to turn this into a "mine is better than yours" post.  We are all here to help.

Comment: David - Feel free to review the following link regarding duplicate answers. http://meta.sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/753/what-should-be-done-about-competing-duplicate-answers

Comment: Again, I didn't copy your answer, it is my own and you simply posted yours faster.  Not to mention this link you provided is not an official stackexchange rule, but a discussion post similar to this one.  I did not at any time say that mine was better.  Mine was just different.  Either way I am done arguing this.  It's really not worth it.  I am not in this for reputation points, I was just trying to help someone out.  I feel this is turning into an argument and is completely unnecessary.  Good day.

Comment: That is why there are voting buttons, the "better" answer rises to the top. While they both point to the same overall end goal, they get there in different ways. They are both good answers and equally deserving of votes. It is up to the asker which is the best for him, regardless of who "firsted".

Comment: I am also not going to comment further on this here as it is best left for over at Meta. Thanks.